# Dúvida como fazer uma thread com select e cancelar query executada no banco

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Eu estou executando uma query dentro de uma thread e setei um tempo limite pra ela executar ou outra forma de parar seria o próprio usuário pode cancelar o `select`. O problema é que eu paro a thread mas a query continua rodando no banco.

Tive a ideia de parar a query com um comando do `postgresql` so q preciso do `pid` da query, e então faço o seguinte select:

```
(
    SELECT
        p.pid
    FROM
        pg_stat_activity p
    WHERE
        state = 'active'
        AND query LIKE '%SELECT * FROM GCEPDC02, pg_sleep(%'
        AND query NOT LIKE '%FROM pg_stat_activity%')
```

mas esse `select` não me retorna nada, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Bom dia Andre.. tudo certinho? Cara nem sabia que dava para rodar uma query por tempo.. Como você setou isso?? ou como se faz isso???

Comment: Opa, eu setei um timer no delphi q qndo der o tempo fecho a thread e faço um select pg_static (algo assim) pra pegar o pid pra cancelar a thread

Comment: ha ta... :) pensei que houvesse alguma propriedade OCULTA que desse para setar :)

Comment: Infelizmente n amigo